# Windows 8 defrag schedule ambiguous

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks, defragment

Windows 8 introduced a new dialog, called "Optimize Drivers", in which they have put a "Scheduled optimization" part. 
We can now choose a schedule for the optimization, but it is unclear to me what exactly does each schedule mean.

If I set it to daily/weekly/monthly, **when will it defrag** during the day/week/month?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for sure so I am not posting as an answer, but I think the answer is "whenever it can". It will watch for the system to go idle, start running it, and stop if you start using it again. If it completes it's job before the next time due it waits the day/week/month until it is time to check again.